# Ifort suppress unused variable warning, leave all others intact

Tags: warnings, compilation, fortran, gfortran, suppress

i use ifort and gfortran to compile my Fortran program.

However i also use a coworkers source and he has got a lot of unused variables. 
How can i suppress these for the compile, seeing as they are not really an error?

However i dont want to disable `-pedantic` and `-stan` in the compiler options and thus want all the other warnings.

cheers and thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With ifort try `-warn [no]unused`.

And, while I'm here, I suggest you remove unused variables.  The compiler may not regard them as an error, but disciplined software engineering regards all dead and unused code as erroneous; it imposes a maintenance burden.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as High Performance Mark pointed out, the best way to get rid of those warnings is to tell your coworker to fix his code.

As for easy solutions, with gfortran, have a look at the `-Wunused-###` options in gcc's manual: [Warning Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html). Notably, `-Wno-unused-variable` might do what you want.

> [...] why the heck would you use gfortran when you have Intel Fortran ?

When developing, running your code through multiple compilers helps in finding bugs and producing portable code.

Comment: +1 for the multiple compilers. It is _very_ useful to test your code with different compilers - especially Fortran with all idioms and different standards.