# Suppress unused variable warning

Tags: fortran, warnings, intel-fortran, unused-variables

What is the best practice in Fortran to suppress warning messages like:

```
remark #7712: This variable has not been used.
```

for just **one** particular variable (imagine function in API that we do not want to break)?

Note: I do not want to [suppress all warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870591/2838364) for a file

Note2: Something similar for gcc: `__attribute__((__unused__))` or [other common C practice with MACRO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3599170/2838364)

Note3: I am particularly interested in ifort, but multi-compiler would be better.

Comment: why not just remove it? or do some simple operation to use it (thats all that c macro does)

Comment: @george Usually you do not remove the variable from function that is exposed via public API. It breaks backward compatibility. The question is what is the best practice, so which operation to use/how to supress it?

Comment: I don't know about best practice, but my current practice is, and has for a long time been, to ignore the warning.  Only justification for this is that, if you modify (say) your build process to mask the warning you run the risk that in future you, well, mask the warning when you no longer ought to.

Comment: Unfortunately lots of warnings make developers ignore them all...

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using Intel Fortran (I can tell from the particular message), you have a couple of options. One is to add a dummy reference, for example:

```
if (.false.) unused=1
```

Another is to disable just unused variable warnings:

```
/warn:all,nounused
```

or for Linux:

```
-warn all,nounused
```

Microsoft Fortran had an interesting library function `UNUSEDQQ` for this purpose - you added a call to `UNUSEDQQ` passing the variable, and this disabled the check. Intel Fortran doesn't support that.